# Alinco DJ-VX50 programming interface

Tags: alinco

I would like to avoid buying overpriced ERW-7 programming cable. I tried several USB/serial interfaces following instructions from other users, e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQT3d-_-kdU

There seems to be hardware dependency - programming application complains about error if the interface is not what it expects (Prolific?). I get error outright when I use CH340 interface. When I try an older PL2303 variant, this error does not appear, but still there is no communication.

Provided that almost all USB/serial adapter and breakout boards are either old Prolific PL2303 chips or Chinese clones, what are the chances to solve this problem?

Original ERW-7 cable costs almost half the price of the whole radio.

Answer (score 1):

I use this cable from BlueMax49ers with my Dj-X11T.  It's a ERW-7 replacement.

https://bluemax49ers.com/product-explorer/dj-x11-prolific-erw-7p-3-ft-radio-programming-cable/

Yes, it still costs money, but much less than the official Alinco cable.

Now if I could only find a cheaper substitute for the ERW-8 USB cable to their charger base...

Answer (score 0):

In fact I realized the cable can be homebrewed easily and I don't need to spend insane price for a highly overpriced cable, which in fact is very simple and common. Selling the cable at high price I consider mean extortion by Alinco.
Original Prolific chip has to be used, not Chinese clone and not other manufacturer. The software checks this and throws an error if the chip is not what Alinco wants you to use. When I receive original FTDI adapter, I will test that one, too.
Connection:

- on the transceiver side use 3.5 mm TRS jack, ring connection is DATA, sleeve connection is GROUND.
- on the adapter side, connect RxD directly to DATA, 10K resistor connect between DATA and +5V, a diode between DATA and TxD, cathode to TxD.

When you switch VX-50 to clone mode, connect the jack, and voila, everything works.
I saved some 1000 CZK (~50 USD) by this simple trick.